# Adding libsqlite3.tbd in IBM MobileFirst 7.1

Tags: sqlite, ibm-mobilefirst

Adding libsqlite3.0.dylib into a MobileFirst Hybrid iOS app build phase, results in JSONStore not being encrypted.

Why is it so? What's the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two JSONStore variants. The one that is bundled in v7.1 and uses OpenSSL, and an open source Cordova plug-in that uses SQLlite.

The open source variant provides a Cordova plug-in you could use in case you're using MFP Cordova apps in v7.1: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/04/01/using-security-in-jsonstore/

You can also attempt the following in order to resolve your error:
https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/